# adb commands in bash script(copying sqlite from android to mac)

Tags: android, bash, sqlite, adb

I need to do same commands by bash script automatically. I'm on Mac and I'm getting tired of doing same thing every time when I want to see my database.

```
./adb shell run-as com.example.wow

chmod 777 databases

cd databases

chmod 777 myDB.db

exit

cat /data/data/com.example.wow/databases/myDB.db > /sdcard/myDB.db

exit

./adb pull /sdcard/myDB.db /Users/
```

Comment: That won't necessarily be trivial, as most of these commands are running on the device rather than the host.  You could try piping them through the shell, but that doesn't always work.  Have you considered adding functionality to a test build of your app to have that export the database?  Or simply maintain it on the External Storage instead for test builds?

Comment: thank you for your quick response,but i didn't understand you quite well,i can say that i only tried to save sqlite programatically,but that didn't work for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like that:

```
#! /bin/bash

cat <<EOF | adb shell
run-as com.example.wow
chmod 777 databases
cd databases
chmod 777 myDB.db
exit
cat /data/data/com.example.wow/databases/myDB.db > /sdcard/myDB.db
exit
EOF
adb pull /sdcard/myDB.db /Users/
```

Comment: thanks, it is working,excuse me but i can't vote Up you i haven't got enough reputation,but i will be back